# How to retrieve data from a database/server when using Cordova?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, cordova

First of all, thank you for reading my question.

Here's my problem: for a small study project, I need to work with Cordova.
I'm trying to retrieve information from a database on my-sql and display it on my Cordova-generated application (I'm on Android). And there's the drama. My code works fine when I display it on "my html web page" but not on my app and I don't know why. I don't know if it's possible. It just shows an empty page with a title "evenement" (events).

I have three codes in my folder, an html code, a server.js code that "starts the server", and a hello.js code that contains a fetch request and a "displayEventDetails" function. Obviously Cordova doesn't like it, so if anyone knows why or knows of another method to achieve the same end?

I'm an apprentice programmer and any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance
Here is my codes :
Html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Affichage d'événements</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Événements :</h1>
<ul id="evenements-list"></ul>

<script src="hello2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

//config link to data base 
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '', // the password is written ;)
    database: '', //same
    charset: 'utf8' // ou un autre encodage approprié
});



//way to get all the events 
app.get('/evenements', (req, res) => {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM evenements', (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('error lors de l\'exécution de la requête :', err);
            return res.status(500).send('Erreur lors de la récupération des événements');
        }

        console.log('Événements :', results); // Ajouter cette ligne pour afficher les résultats

        res.json(results);
    });
});


// Démarrer le serveur
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Serveur en écoute sur le port 3000');
});
```

and my hello.js

```
//function which displays the events on the html page
function afficherDetailsEvenement(evenement) {
    const { id, titre, localisation, meteo, description } = evenement;

    const ulElement = document.getElementById('evenements-list');
    const liElement = document.createElement('li');
    liElement.innerHTML = `
        <p>ID: ${id}</p>
        <p>Titre: ${titre}</p>
        <p>Localisation: ${localisation}</p>
        <p>Météo: ${meteo}</p>
        <p>Description: ${description}</p>
    `;
    ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
}

// recuperation of the elements with fetch 
fetch('http://localhost:3000/evenements') //Or with the ip adress
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const evenements = data;
        console.log('Événements :', evenements);

        evenements.forEach(evenement => {
            afficherDetailsEvenement(evenement);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('errorlors de la récupération des événements :', error);
    });
```

I have tried many things:

-doing minor changes on my codes but the result is the same
-changing the rules in the config.xml of the cordova file by adding :

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" /> //with the adress of 
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
```

-changing the port
-trying to display "number of events: " + the number of events to see if on my app it shows 0 or nothing. It have shown nothing.
-downloading plugins for cordova

I just think the link between the server and my app doesn't work

Comment: I'd suggest deciding on your database engine first; MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products and libraries designed for one rarely work for the other.

Comment: i use MySql my bad

Comment: Then you should remove the tag [[tag:sql-server]] from your question.

Comment: "I just think the link between the server and my app doesn't work" - yes, because you call `localhost:3000` in your app (hello.js), on the phone, but your server is not there on your phone. Bind your server app to your local IP or put it on a remote host, and call that IP/domain from your app.

Comment: i have replaced localhost by the ip v4 adress on my computer and it doesn't work neither but thanks for the sugestion of the remote host i will try even if i prefer work on local

Comment: the problem seems to be related to the phone i used. On an another phone it works. Some phone blocks request i do in my code i guess. I can surely change that in the parameters of the phone